# How Do I total all the variables? in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How do I add all the variables in VB.net? I do what I was instructed to increment it by placing it outside. Now that I have done it whenever I press the button the output is only 95 and whenever I click multiple times on the picturebox with the incrementation the output is still the same from last time. Nothing is really happening

```
Private BibimbapQuantity = 1
Private BulgogiQuantity = 1
Private BibimbapPrice As Integer = 45 * BibimbapQuantity
Private BulgogiPrice As Integer = 50 * BulgogiQuantity
Private TotalPriceInt As Integer = BibimbapPrice + BulgogiPrice
Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonBibimbap.Click
    BibimbapQuantity += 1
    Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add("Bibimbap", "1", BibimbapPrice)

End Sub

Private Sub buttonBulgogi_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonBulgogi.Click
    BulgogiQuantity += 1
    Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add("Bulgogi", "1", BulgogiPrice)

End Sub

Private Sub totalPrice_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles totalPrice.Click


End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    totalPrice.Text = TotalPriceInt
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You might've written the formula at the top but it's only executed once. You need to execute the formula every time.

```
Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonBibimbap.Click
    BibimbapQuantity += 1
    BibimbapPrice = 45 * BibimbapQuantity ' <------

    Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add("Bibimbap", "1", BibimbapPrice)

End Sub
```

You'll need to do the same with the total.

When you are done, put your code in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ they will help you a lot with refactoring it. *Only post on codereview when the code is actually working. They will help you find better way of writing your logic and find possible problems. Great learning opportunity.*